# Уменьшение ширины дива с max-width, если текст переносится на другую строку

Tags: css

Есть ли в css возможность указать блоку с установленной максимальной шириной, что если текст не вмещается в 1 строку, то нужна не максимальная ширина, а конкретно по ширине текста?

Т.е. чтобы первый блок выглядел как 2.

```css
.test {
  max-width: 500px;
  background: red;
  padding: 10px;
  word-wrap: normal;
}

.test2 {
  max-width: 380px;
  background: red;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
Введите  адрес  Вашей  электронной  почты,  например, text@example123.ru.
</div>
<br/>
<div class="test2">
 Введите  адрес  Вашей  электронной  почты,  например, text@example123.ru.
</div>
```

Comment: замена max-width на min-width не подходит? + float:left

Comment: @Maximmka, не подходит. Это всплывающая подсказка. Если не указать max-width, она будет шириной во весь экран.

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать использовать `min-width` и `display: inline-block`, пример в классе `test3`. Свойство `word-break: break-all;` из `test4` переносит не помещающиеся символы.

```css
.test {
  max-width: 500px;
  background: red;
  padding: 10px;
  word-wrap: normal;
}
.test2 {
  max-width: 380px;
  background: red;
  padding: 10px;
}
.test3 {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 380px;
  background: red;
  padding: 10px;
}
.test4 {
  max-width: 380px;
  background: red;
  padding: 10px;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  Введите адрес Вашей электронной почты, например, text@example123.ru.
</div>
<br/>
<div class="test2">
  Введите адрес Вашей электронной почты, например, text@example123.ru.
</div>
<br/>
<div class="test3">
  Введите адрес Вашей электронной почты, например, text@example123.ru.
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<div class="test4">
  Введите адрес Вашей электронной почты, например, text@example123.ru.
</div>
```

Comment: К сожалению, как я написал выше, max-width нужен, чтобы всплывающее окно не было в ширину экрана. Видимо, придется оставлять так или использовать `word-break: break-all`.